# Byte sequence change when cast char* to unsigned short* and dereference?

Tags: c

```
unsigned short* pname = (unsigned short*)(buf + buf_offset);/*sequence problem?*/
unsigned short pointer_offset = ntohs(*pname) & COMPRESSION_MASK;
```

Here, buf_offset == 0. the content of buf is [c0] [0c] .However, the *pname is [0x0cc0]. What is the problem? Thank you.

Comment: What is the type of `buf`? Can you show a bit more code to make this more clear?

Comment: ntohs() swaps the byte order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have pointed out, the code you have posted is not portable. It's not just for the reason of endianness. Casting from `char *` to `unsigned short *` may also cause [bus errors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault#Bus_error_example), due to invalid alignment. Additionally, there may be padding bits in an `unsigned short` that cause your program to misbehave, or an `unsigned short` might be smaller or larger than "2 bytes" depending on `CHAR_BIT` and the choices of the implementation. The overall issue is internal representation of types, and you can avoid this issue by using operators that behave the same regardless of internal representation. Perhaps you meant:

```
unsigned short offset = (unsigned char) buf[0];
offset *= (UCHAR_MAX + 1);
offset += (unsigned char) buf[1];
offset &= COMPRESSION_MASK;
```

If you want big endian, you must explicitly state that you want it. By multiplying `buf[0]` and adding `buf[1]`, I'm specifying that `buf[0]` is more significant than `buf[1]`, hence I'm explicitly specifying that I want big endian. Multiplications and additions work the same in every C implementation, and there are no alignment issues.

Reversing the conversion:

```
unsigned char buf[2] = { offset / (UCHAR_MAX + 1), offset % (UCHAR_MAX + 1) };
```

It'd be nice to see more code written without care of internal representation!

Comment: @user2172495: I just noticed a bug in my code. Note the edits to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

it depend on your platform , big-endian / little-endian
you should change the byte order.

```
#ifdef _BIG_ENDIAN_ 
    // revers bytes order
#endif
```

Comment: How can I check if my platform is BIG or small Ending? My cup is intel. OS is window 8.

Answer (score 0):

ntohs() swaps the byte order to big endian

Comment: In the buf, 0xc0 is in lower memory address. However, after the cast to unsigned short, the 0xc0 is in high memory address.(small endian).Is that strange?

Answer (score 0):

As gabriel mentioned,

The ntohs() converts a u_short from TCP/IP network byte order to host byte order (which is little-endian on Intel processors).

The ntohs function returns the value in host byte order. If the parameter passed is already in host byte order, then this function will reverse it. It is up to the application to determine if the byte order must be reversed.

Comment: yes, my program is to convert DNS answer bytes to host value.And seems different DNS send different order answer.